# Invalid character issue

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mulesoft, mule-esb

Need small help to handle below scenario.

Receiving one on the element/attribute as Muñiz  from payload from source system(Workday) and using SFTP Write operation and SFTP Write is placing this value as  MuÃ±iz in .csv file.

Source system team is saying they can't change this value  Muñiz  in workday and asking us to handle in Mulesoft only...  so we used in data transformation(as below 2nd step) before writing file into SFTP Write as below.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv
encoding="UTF-8"
```

Processor in Mule flow in below order,

1. HTTP Request Call to Workday    - Getting one of the atributes Muñiz in
   response from Workday
2. Data tranformation
3. Pgp encrypt
4. SFTP Write

When we see the payload value in debug just before Pgp encrypt then it is showing as Muñiz

And when we open file in folder which has placed by SFTP Write then this value is showing  MuÃ±iz in .csv file

Note: I read one document to use BOM (Byte Order Mark) to handle these kind of cases but not sure how to use and handle by using BOM.  Not sure whether do we need to use BOM or any simple kind of option we have in Mule.

Can anyone write code in simple mule flow and share it here so that I will use same code ?

Final OUTPUT should be write in .csv as : Muniz

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small app using an HTTP `POST` request to pass all kind of "funky" characters and in my case I am able to read and write the "funky" characters:

Here's the request:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://localhost:8081/csv \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
    "lastName": "Muñiz",
    "greek": "Ο καθηγητής Χ. Γώγος στον ΣΚΑΪ",
    "hebrew": "עִבְרִית"
}'
```

Here's the XML of the app:

```
<mule xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config"
        doc:name="HTTP Listener config"
        doc:id="100ea742-8e79-4703-a162-8400fb676aa6">
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0"
            port="8081" />
    </http:listener-config>
    <flow name="munozFlow"
        doc:id="7f291db1-f477-49e7-bb12-8b8bfeb2ff71">
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener"
            doc:id="7fdbcd73-a2bd-433b-a04a-098ff02e2cdc"
            config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/csv" />
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message"
            doc:id="1c2d63a3-9b60-472c-8cd8-3df5e1671ad9">
            <ee:message>
                <ee:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/csv
---
payload]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <file:write doc:id="61da842e-aa0e-46e8-85e4-c7ad349504bf"
            path='#["tmp/output-" ++ (now() as String {format: "yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS"}) ++ ".csv"]' />
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Finally, here's the resulting CSV file:

```
lastName,greek,hebrew
Muñiz,Ο καθηγητής Χ. Γώγος στον ΣΚΑΪ,עִבְרִית
```

In conclusion, if you have the right encoding to the text you get from Workday then Mule will be able to accommodate.  I bet whatever Workday operation you are using is not providing you with the right encoding.

Also verify that you are using a application that can display "funky" characters when displaying the contents of the file.

Comment: I have updated my question in complete case to understand easily, can you please check once and respond ?

Comment: Nah I still don't understand.  Update your question maybe with the XML of your app--preferably self-contained so that I can use it verbatim on my own app.  Moreover, ensure it is propertly formatted following SO's editing rules so that code/data are clearly identified.

Comment: can you please update your code which should result in CSV file as  Muniz  by taking input as Muñiz   ?    I need final result as Muniz

Answer (score 0):

If the objective is to replace some specific characters in the CSV output, you can use replace() using the Unicode escape character sequence.

Example:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv
fun replaceChars(s)=s replace "\u00F1" with("n")
---
payload map ($ mapObject ($$): replaceChars($))
```

Input:

```
[{
    "name": "Mu\u00F1iz",
    "address": "Main Street 11"
}]
```

Output:

```
name,address
Muniz,Main Street 11
```